# проблема с awt.graphics

Tags: java, graphics, awt

При попытке вызвать `paintComponent` с передачей аргументов происходит ошибка, если я удаляю аргументы и назначаю внутри `paintComponent` свои все работает.

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at fg.draw.paintComponent(draw.java:10)
>       at fg.mane.bla(mane.java:18)
>       at fg.mane.main(mane.java:13)
>           package fg;

Код:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mane {
    static draw d=new draw();
    public static void main(String[]args){
        frame f=new frame();
        f.f1.setSize(200,200);
        f.f1.setVisible(true);
        f.f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.f1.add(d);
        bla();
    }
    public static void bla(){
        int b1=10;
        int b2=10;
        d.paintComponent(null, b1, b2);
    }

}

        package fg;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class draw extends JLabel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g,int x,int y){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);

    }

}

package fg;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class frame {
    JFrame f1=new JFrame();

}
```

Comment: Эээ... ну Вы же первым параметром передаете тот самый `null`.

Comment: @post_zeew а что передавать в paintComponent?

Comment: Объект класса `Graphics`.

Comment: @post_zeew не работает

Comment: @NINZA Вам пытаются сказать, что Вы пытаетесь нарисовать несуществующий компонент - первый аргумент метода `paintComponent`, это то, что Вы собрались рисовать, а там `null`)

Answer (score 1):

надо передавать объект `Graphics` внутрь метода `paintComponent()`, а вы передаете `NULL`. из за чего `NULL.setColor(Color.BLACK)`; вернет вам NPE

используйте следующий код

```
 public static void bla() {
    int b1 = 10;
    int b2 = 10;
    d.paintComponent(d.getGraphics(), b1, b2);
}
```